# Docker doesn't find the directory

Tags: docker

I'm trying to get my hands on Docker and write my own gitea image without using docker compose.

The snippet of code that doesn't seem to be working is below, the second line is what returns an error.

```
RUN useradd -u 8877 test
RUN wget -O /tmp/gitea <link> && mv /tmp/gitea /home/test && chmod +x /home/test/gitea
```

However, when moving my file from the tmp to "test" users home directory (I run the dockerfile as root), it claims that the gitea file doesn't exist. I can't see any issue in the paths, I expect it all to run without an issue as in my eyes, that directory exists.

Error message:

```
cannot access '/home/test/gitea': Not a directory
```

Is my pathing wrong or have I gone wrong somewhere else?

Edit from answer: Downloading directly to that directory throws the same error "No such file or directory"

Answer (score 1):

Solved!

Turns out creating a user doesn't create a directory for them. Adding the flags -rm -d into the "useradd" adds a /home/user directory and therefore the pathing now exists.

Comment: (Since a Docker container only runs a single process with a temporary filesystem, it's a little unusual for a "home directory" to exist in the normal Unix way.  Consider installing the application into `/usr/local`, a subdirectory of `/opt`, or just `/app`.)

Answer (score 0):

Why not download directly?

```
RUN wget -O /home/test/gitea <link> && chmod +x /home/test/gitea
```

Comment: That was an attempt I made, but it throws back the same error, "No such file or directory" which leads me to believe that the users home directory either doesn't exist, or my path is wrong.